# How do I create a batch table for 3D Tiles in Blender

Tags: export, gltf

Blender 2.8 supports the export into gltf which can be converted into a b3dm file to use it as a 3D Tile in CesiumJS.
How can I keep attributes on each feature in Blender so that they will be exported into gltf and later b3dm. These attributes needed to be kept for each feature in order to create queries for them in Cesium.

Comment: I think the Cesium team released an addon related to this.  I don't know if it keeps attributes or not.  https://cesium.com/blog/2019/07/08/blender-addon/

Comment: Yes, but this just uploads the tiles to Cesium Ion, but I want to keep the tiles on my own server. Found that the Blender glTF export keeps the attributes, but does not generates features which are needed to query the attributes. Feature count stays always at 0.

Comment: @SnoopyBrown, I had the same problem, did you find any way to export as features?

Comment: No, never found a solution, unfortunately. I used py3dtiles to export my objects where I could modify the code to create at least one feature. This isn’t supported well at all now.